# how awoid 2 times re render in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

i have tried to do routing according to user check and i did but my method worked two times. i understand it from my log

i'm using redux and here is my "useeffect" in mainrouter.js

```
// currentUser : null // in  initialState for users

useEffect(() => {
    if(states.currentUser== null)
    {
        console.log("Checking user for routing");
        actions.getCurrentUserACT();
    }
    else{
        console.log("Logged in")
    }
},[]);
```

my mainrouter.js return

```
 return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        {
            states.currentUser == null ?
                (this.SignStackScreen()) :
                (this.MainTabNavigator())
        }
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

here is my "getCurrentUserAct" method in redux actions

```
export function getCurrentUserACT() {
return function (dispatch) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            console.log("User authed..");
            dispatch({type:actionTypes.CURRENT_USER,payload:user})
        } else {
            console.log("User notauthed..");
            dispatch({type:actionTypes.CURRENT_USER,payload:null})
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

when my app start, logs are .. (if i logged in before)

- Checking user for routing
- User authed
- User authed

i think the reason for this, useeffect worked first time and state changed which use in return and rerender"
but then i removed to condition, logs were same.

so how i can avoid this? 
is there a way to run method before from useeffect and avoid second render? or wait data in useeffect?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right and there is no reason to log two times because of useEffect because you used it as componentDidMount so it is called one time.

The reason of logging two times is this code snippet:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
```

here onAuthStateChanged is callback and it is called when state of authentication changed on Firebase.
If you are going to check if the user logged in then you need to avoid to do like below

```
if (user) { }
```

Please try console.log(user) and check if user keeps same on double logging.
I believe user inner properties will be changed.

Hope this helps you to understand

Comment: If i logged in before, user properties did not change. But i log out and logged in again, logs work well

Comment: Did you check action again? Please let me see the action in case of CURRENT_USER

Comment: i share it as a new post @Bojan

Comment: please check mainrouter.js if state.current_user is null for two times. in my opinion that part is most suspicious. how did you get states? like const states = {....} ?

Comment: i get mapstatetoprops all states. currentUser state's initial value is null 
function mapStateToProps(state) { return { states: { currentUser: state.currentUserReducer, }}
}

Comment: you are doing something wrong in reducer, just try like this --- return { ...states, {currentUser: state.currentUserReducer}};

Comment: i cant understand "return { ...state......."  my friend. i returned states variable and its include currentUser. Then ı used like this in main router "const MainRouter = ({ actions, 'states' }) => {
 "  
so i can use like "...states"

Comment: is there a way to run an action before useeffect first firing ?

Comment: yes, you can run an action at first line of the function component.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function getCurrentUserACT() {
return function (dispatch) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        dispatch(setCurrentUserACT(user))
        console.log("control point" + user);
        // if (user) {
        //     console.log("User authed..");
        //     dispatch({type:actionTypes.CURRENT_USER,payload:user})
        // } else {
        //     console.log("User notauthed..");
        //     dispatch({type:actionTypes.CURRENT_USER,payload:null})
        // }
    });
}
```

Logs were double

- Checking user for routing
- control point[object Object]
- control point[object Object]

______________________Edited 31.05______________________

I change my code a little bit like below

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.currentUserReducer);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(currentUser));
    if (currentUser == null) {
        console.log("Checking user for routing");
        //dispatch(getCurrentUserACT());
    }
    else {
        console.log("Logged in")
    }
}, []);
```

I found something like hint but I can't fix because i dont know
When app start logs are

- null
- Checking user for routing

I didnt dispatch getCurrentUserAct(), so logs are right. If i dispatch, user will be checking (user already logged in), component rerender and here is double logs from double render.

I need dispatch before useeffect, not in useeffect

Is there a way?